How can i Modify a data file that is contained inside a One File Pyinstaller EXXE
I am using the command pyinstaller -F --add-data="token;." Main.py for my code.
i want to be able to change the contents of the token file and it stay like that after i rerun it
i tried to modify the file normally but because its in a temp folder it only stays on this session

When are you trying to change the token file? Are you trying to update the token file pre-packaging or have the token file update when you run your packaged exe file?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

While you use PyInstaller with the -F (or --onefile) option, the PyInstaller extracts the contents into a temporary folder, which is deleted after the program exits, thus you can't make changes after a while.
# Define the persistent directory
persistent_dir = 
  os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),'your_application_data')
  os.makedirs(persistent_dir, exist_ok=True)

# Define the path to the token file in the persistent directory
persistent_token_path = os.path.join(persistent_dir, 'token')

# Now, always use the token file from the persistent directory
with open(persistent_token_path, 'r') as token_file:
token = token_file.read()

